# ActionView::Template::Error "Invalid CSS" thrown in feature spec only

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, phantomjs, capybara

The following Sass works perfectly in development:

```
main
  :not(table) img
    +box-shadow
```

But when I run my specs, as soon as a JavaScript feature spec is run (which compiles CSS first), it throws the following error:

```
#<ActionView::Template::Error: Invalid CSS after "  not(table): img": expected "{", was ";">
```

I have no idea why this only shows in tests, and not in development. Any ideas?